# EF Core 6, GroupBy with inner collection Sum

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I want to create a query which will group a set by some criteria, and it will create a result set witch will contain the sum of some inner list.

This is my query, which fails:

```
var invoices = await _dbContext.Beneficiaries
                 .Where(dbEntry => dbEntry.Id == beneficiaryId && dbEntry.ProviderId == providerId)
                 .SelectMany(dbEntry => dbEntry.Invoices)
                 .GroupBy(dbEntry => dbEntry.IssueDate.Month)
                 .Select(dbEntry => new
                 {
                     IssueMonth = dbEntry.Key,
                     VAT = dbEntry.Max(invoice => invoice.VAT),
                     TotalPay = dbEntry.Select(invoice => invoice.InvoiceEntries.Sum(entry => entry.DelegateHourlyRate)).Max(),
                     TotalSell = dbEntry.Select(invoice => invoice.InvoiceEntries.Sum(entry => entry.BeneficiaryHourlyRate)).Max(),
                 })
            .Where(group => group.IssueMonth <= _todayDate.UtcNow.Month && group.IssueMonth >= _todayDate.UtcNow.Month - (int)by)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Following is the class hierarchy

```
public class Beneficiary
{
    public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public ICollection<InvoiceEntry> InvoiceEntries { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceEntry
{
    public decimal DelegateHourlyRate { get; set; }
    public decimal BeneficiaryHourlyRate { get; set; }
}
```

This is the exception I'm getting with EF version 5.0.9.

> The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector:
> b.IssueDate, ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: EntityType:
> Invoice ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: True .Max(invoice =>
> invoice.InvoiceEntries.Count)' could not be translated. Either rewrite
> the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
> evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

This is the exception I'm getting with EF version 6.0.8.

> SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression
> containing an aggregate or a subquery. Cannot perform an aggregate
> function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Another variation

```
var invoices2 = await _dbContext.Beneficiaries
     .Where(dbEntry => dbEntry.Id == beneficiaryId && dbEntry.ProviderId == providerId)
     .SelectMany(dbEntry => dbEntry.Invoices
         .GroupBy(dbEntry => dbEntry.IssueDate.Month)
         .Select(dbEntry => new
         {
             IssueMonth = dbEntry.Key,
             VAT = dbEntry.Sum(invoice => invoice.VAT),
             TotalPay = dbEntry.Sum(invoice => invoice.InvoiceEntries.Sum(entry => entry.DelegateHourlyRate)),
             TotalSell = dbEntry.Sum(invoice => invoice.InvoiceEntries.Sum(entry => entry.BeneficiaryHourlyRate))
         }))
 .Where(group => group.IssueMonth <= _todayDate.UtcNow.Month && group.IssueMonth >= _todayDate.UtcNow.Month - (int)by)
 .ToListAsync();
```

Which results in

> SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression
> containing an aggregate or a subquery. Cannot perform an aggregate
> function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
> aggregate or a subquery. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an
> expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Fyi, apart from the query itself, you know that you group by month only? Maybe you should include the year: `.GroupBy(dbEntry => new{dbEntry.IssueDate.Year,dbEntry.IssueDate.Month})`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of only the month grouping. At this point I'm looking just for a method to sum up the inner collection

Comment: Why you have used `Select` and `Max`? Why not just `Sum`?

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? I'm not getting any error with your query in EF Core 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, it should be another `SelectMany`. Rewritten query in Query Syntax for readability and change time range condition for using table indexes, if they are exist for sure.

```cs
var current = _todayDate.UtcNow;
var prev = current.Date.AddMonths(-1);

var query = 
    from b in _dbContext.Beneficiaries
    from invoice in b.Invoices
    where invoice.IssueDate <= current && invoice.IssueDate >= prev
    from invoiceEntry in invoice.InvoiceEntries
    group new { invoice, invoiceEntry } by new { invoice.IssueDate.Year, invoice.IssueDate.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        IssueMonth = g.Key.Month,
        VAT = g.Max(x => x.invoice.VAT),
        TotalPay = g.Sum(x => x.invoiceEntry.DelegateHourlyRate),
        TotalSell = g.Sum(x => x.invoiceEntry.BeneficiaryHourlyRate)
    };

var invoices = query.ToList();
```

Comment: You are missing `Max` after `Select(..)`. So it is not another `SelectMany`. Also OP example works in EFC 6, so probably they need a workaround for some older version (unknown at this time)

Comment: @IvanStoev, I know, maybe OP written bad query for Total. But if it explain `Max` usage, I will rewrite this query to do anything.

Comment: Max of Sum, what's the problem of having query like that?

Comment: Do you think it needs `Max` for column `TotalPay`? Let's wait for the answer.

Comment: I've updated the question, and I've included package versions. Prev version was 5.0.9

Comment: What is the reason to use `Sum + Max`? This is my question. And does my answer meets your needs?